# Overlay an image on top of slider

Tags: css, image, slider

I want to lay an image on top of my slider - the scrolls on either side of the images in the slider. [BitsyBride.com](http://bitsybride.com)

Right now they are prev next links but, as you can see by resizing your browser, they jump around. I am throwing in the towel on that issue and just want them to be a decorative image.

So, how do I place an image on top of this?

```
#sliderwrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://bitsybride.com/wp-content/themes/basement/images/linen3.png);
}
```

Comment: Placing these images inside your div `#mygallery` would make it a lot easier! And more logical as well.

Comment: This is totally unrelated, but the first impression i got in your website is that it's name "bitchy" not bitsy, you might want to think about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where would you recommend I put it in mygallery?

```
#mygallery{ padding:0;position: relative;}

.stepcarousel{
position: relative; /*leave this value alone*/
overflow: scroll; /*leave this value alone*/
width: 980px; /*Width of Carousel Viewer itself*/
height:300px; /*Height should enough to fit largest content's height*/
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}

 .stepcarousel .belt{
position: absolute; /*leave this value alone*/
left: 0;
top: 0px;
}

 .stepcarousel .panel{
float: right; /*leave this value alone*/
margin:0 40px 0 0;
border:none;
 }

 .thumb-title{
top:-105px;
right:0;
display:block;
position:absolute;
width: 250px; height:68px;
background: #eee url(images/line-h-l.png) top repeat-x;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
text-shadow:0 1px 1px #333;
}   



 .thumb-title-clear{
padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
height:48px;
overflow:hidden;
}

 .thumb-title h2 a {
display:block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:16pt;
line-height:18pt;
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
font-weight:bold;
}

 .thumb-title h2 a:hover { 
}



 .stepcarousel .slideimg{
 float: left; /*leave this value alone*/
 background: #000 /*clip content that go outside dimensions of holding panel DIV*/
 margin:0; /*margin around each panel*/
 padding:0;   
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-radius:15px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
 }
```

Comment: Also, would it be something like this?      .stepcarousel .nav{
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 background image: 
     }

Comment: Got it. .nav{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
     margin-left: -580px;
 z-index: 100;
}